# ConnectionFailedTransientException on New-InboxRule

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, rules

I am trying to create Mailbox Rules on my users to automatically Junk mail marked as SPAM by our MTA.

Using my main account as a test account, I am running the following:

```
new-inboxrule -name “Auto-junk S-P-A-M” -mailbox “*mailboxname*” -MoveToFolder ‘*mailboxname*:\Junk E-Mail' -SubjectContainsWords “S-P-A-M” -StopProcessingRules $true
```

Unfortunately, EMS is returning the following:

```
Cannot open mailbox /o=*Organisation*/ou=First Administrative Group/cn=Recipients/cn=*mailboxname*
    + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified (0:Int32) [New-InboxRule], ConnectionFailedTransientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 9C28F133, Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewInboxRule
```

The administrative account I am using to effect these changes does not have `FullMailboxAccess` on the test account, but is part of the `Organization Management`, `Recipient Management` & `Help Desk` OUs in the Exchange Security Groups.

Have I missed a required Permission Group to effect this change, do I have to do something to force Exchange 2010 to pick up AD changes (I only recently added the user to `Recipient Management` and `Help Desk`) - restart IIS? - or is FullMailboxAccess the only sure-fire solution?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, but on 2013. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: No, I was not. I tell users what to do if they request it, but some form of automation would be good.

Answer (score 1):

If you use -MoveToFolder the user who is execute the powershell command NEED a mailbox on the exchange server.

Secondary the actual user need to have full access (only read-access I did not checked) to the mailbox where you create the InboxRule (what you cannot configure, if the user did not have an mailbox on the server) ...

An Admin-User without a mailbox or without the permission cannot read the Folder-Structure from the mailbox where you want to create the rule.